# Apply css style to child element of parent class

Tags: html, css, angularjs

i need to aply a css for a input if his parent is a special class (closeorder)
In this html:

```
<autocomplete id="items" placeholder="Buscar trabajos" pause="400" selectedobject="selectedObject" 
   url="http://localhost:801/categories/query/New Company/" 
   titlefield="type,code,name,price" descriptionfield="Categoria, Codigo, Nombre, Precio" 
   inputclass="form-control form-control-small selector closeoder" 
   class="ng-isolate-scope">
      <div class="input-group autocomplete-holder">
         <form ng-submit="submit()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <button data-toggle="tooltip" title="Añadir seleccion" class="btn btn-tr btn-link animated pulse- btn" style="color:#81BB31; font-size:20px;">
               <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
         </form>
         <input id="search_value" ng-model="searchStr" type="text" 
            placeholder="Buscar trabajos" class="selector ng-pristine ng-valid">
      </div>
</autocomplete>
```

The autocomplete element has inputclass closeorder, how can i set css to the input child?

I tried with this:

```
autocomplete.closeorder > input {
    width: 88% !important;
}
```

but dont work..

Comment: autocomplete.closeorder > input[type="text"]{ width: 88% !important;} should work! so you need to define what type input is

Comment: I don't see a closeorder class in the markup.

Comment: and your input is not an immediate children of <autocomplete>

Comment: "closeoder" need to be in class="" not in inputclass. Then will be "autocomplete.closeorder input"

Comment: is `autocomplete` a valid tag?  If so I would use `autocomplete.closeorder .autocomplete-holder > input`

Comment: It is ver surprising that so many wrong suggestions have come up. People, `closeorder` is **not** a class ! And OP does not need to convert it to a class just because you happen to know the `.class` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complete list of CSS selectors take a look **[here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)**.
Basically, you seem to need these two selectors:

**E[foo~="bar"]**
*an E element whose "foo" attribute value is a list of whitespace-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to "bar"*

**E F**
*an F element descendant of an E element*

---

The CSS rule should look like this:

```
autocomplete[inputclass~="closeoder"] input {
    ...
}
```

This reads:
Select any `input` element that is a descendant of an `autocomplete` element whose "inputclass" attribute value is a list of whitespace-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to "closeorder".

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/c3d3f/)**.

---

<sub>(Using `!important` is rarely a good idea. Learn about **[CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)** and try to avoid `!imporant` as much as possible.)</sub>

Comment: This dont do nothing to my element..:S

Comment: Maybe it has to do with how the autocomplete directive is handling things. So, how it autocomplete defined ?

Comment: I just noticed: Is it `closeoder` or `closeorder` ? Maybe it is because of a typo.

Comment: @colymore: I corrected the possible typo (`closeorder` --> `closeoder`) and added a link to a short demo that shows it works.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of a couple of errors. First remove `inputclass` and use `class`

Fix the typo to closeorder in the HTML

and finally use this CSS

```
.closeorder input[type="text"]{
    width: 88%;
}
```

The !important is not necessary and you should used the !important hack as least as possible.

See [***DEMO***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FDklr/)